# Spring Boot Security filter chain has error

Tags: spring, security, filter, chain

when i user Spring Boot Security filter chain insted of WebscurityconfigurerAdapter has error...

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.csrf()
            .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE)
            .hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/admin/**")
            .hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/user/**")
            .hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/login/**")
            .anonymous()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

    return http.build();
}
```

----  httpSecurity NOT recognize  -------

```
@Bean
public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
    return (web) -> web.ignoring().antMatchers("/ignore1", "/ignore2");
}
```

***** antMatchers  has error *****[tag:Spring BootSecurity filterChain]

---

Comment: What is not recgonized? Are you using the correct imports?